# routes content does not show in Vue-router and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Im following this [YT tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJN_7YJkzRw&t=4s), I followed the steps but it seems that the `ExampleComponent` does not show. The `App.vue` shows but not the route.

Here are my code:

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import App from './components/App';

require('./bootstrap');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        App
    },
    router,
});
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent';

Vue.use(VueRouter);


export default new VueRouter({
    routes : [
        { path : '/', component : ExampleComponent }
    ],
    mode: 'history'
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1> Hello!</h1>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name : "App"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    
</style>
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <App></App>
    </div>
</body>
```

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/{any}', 'HomeController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any error in console .?

Comment: There is none. But the component does not work. But vue-router is ^3.4.5 and the vue is ^2.5.17... Im not sure if that is the issue

Comment: what is your `web.php` .? put that as well

Comment: Try out `mode: 'hash'` instead of `mode: 'history'`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim OMG, the hash works. Why is that? Im using Firefox Dev btw

Comment: oh are you using url like `foldername/public` .?

Comment: @KamleshPaul, yes, im doing in local right now.

Comment: @Miro use `php artisan serve` in devlopment in production it will work (if you use root domain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the mode from `history` to `hash` because the history mode in this case is reserved to Laravel routing system :

```
export default new VueRouter({
routes : [
    { path : '/', component : ExampleComponent }
],
mode: 'hash'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mode: 'hash'` is a great solution.

But if u want to use `mode: "history"` Then you have to add  `base` Parameter . `Base` is useful when the application is hosted inside of a folder like `http://localhost/laravel-8/`. So code rewrite like following -

```
export default new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    base: '/laravel-8/',
    fallback:true,
    routes : [
        { path : '/', component : ExampleComponent }
    ]
})
```

Instead of `/laravel-8/`, you use your project subdirectory name.

Documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#moved-the-base-option