# vue router-view doesn't appear anything

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

there is no error in my code or console. But my router-view doesn't appear anything. I work with laravel 7 in this project

This is my app.js

```js
// import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import App from './components/App';
import Newsfeed from "./views/Newsfeed";
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require("vue");
   
Vue.use(VueRouter);
    
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Newsfeed },
]
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
})
    
const app = new Vue({
    components: {
        App
    },
    router: router
}).$mount('#app');
```

This is my App.vue

```html
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col flex-1 h-screen overflow-y-hidden">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
    name: "App"
}
</script>
```

This is my Newsfeed.vue

```html
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center py-4">
        Hello
    </div>
</template>
  
<script>
export default {
    name: "Newsfeed"
}
</script>
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: put your `web.php` as well

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64115871/8172857

Comment: This is my web.php in routes

Auth::routes();

Route::get('{any}', 'AppController@index')
    ->where('any', '.*')
    ->middleware('auth')->name('home');

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i put mode in hash still doesn't appear anythin